# regex to find strings that start with a backslash

Tags: java, regex, backslash

I'm looking for a regular expression that finds Strings that start with a backslash.

"^\", "^\\" and "^\\\" don't work at all and "^\\\\" just finds strings that start with 2 backslashes.

I'm using Java btw.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need regex here, just use:

```
boolean b = string.startsWith("\\");
```

to check if given string starts with a backslash.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to do it with regex though? Because I need it for a MongoDB query (should have mentioned that in the question, sorry)

Comment: With regex you can do: `string.matches("\\\\.*");` (double escape the backslash)

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `\` is a special char in Java. So in order to the regex to detect the `\` character you need to escape it on the string. For example `"\test"` would print as a tab followed by `est`. `"\\test"` would be printed correctly.

Regarding the regex itself, it should be `"^\\\\"` as you need to escape the backslash there as well.

Comment: Please make use of backticks or indenting (code formatting) when appropriate.  If you don't, we can't tell if your answer is wrong or if it just got mangled by the site's automatic formatting.  For example, the regex in the last line contained three backslashes, but looked like it had only two, and should have had four. (I fixed it.)